# Cannot redirect to the dashboard (secret page) after signing up

Tags: node.js, passport.js, passport-local

I'm trying to redirect to my secret page after signing up, but it seems like this is not working.
Actually, after completing and submitting the form by clicking on the register button my username and password keep showing on my URL.

I think the problem is that I'm working with GoormIde, I don't know what's the changes need to be done when working with an Ide.

This is my full code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    passport = require("passport"),
    User = require("./models/user"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    localStrategy = require("passport-local"),
    passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")


// Connecting to the Mongoose Server
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://plvtinum:*******@cluster0-pjomo.gcp.mongodb.net/auth2?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
    }).then(() => {
    console.log('Connect to DB!');
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
});


var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "Rusty is the best dog in the world",   
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
 }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

//================
// ROUTES
//================

// Home Page
app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
});

// Secret Page
app.get("/secret",function(req,res){
    res.render("secret");

});

// Auth Routes

// Show sign up form
app.get("/register", function(req, res){
    res.render("register");
});

// Handling user sign up
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password, function(err, user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return res.render('register');
        }
        passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
           res.redirect("/secret");
        });
    });
});


// Listening On port 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Server Has Started!!");   
  });
```

Comment: can you post the local strategy function implementation?

Comment: I edited my code so you can clearly understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

```js
app.post("/register",function(req,res){
    User.register(new User({username: req.body.username}), req.body.password,function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/register");
        }
        else
        {
            passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
                res.redirect("/secret");
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Returning of the register form seems to cause some unexplainable error i suppose